# Two inner joins in one SQL query string

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to get information from three tables. I have a 'worker' table which includes a store ID (store_idStore) and a job ID (job_idJob) as foreign keys. In the Store and Job tables, each of them has a 'Name' field - this is the data I want to return in my query along with all of the information from Worker. My only caveat is that I have to put the query into a string in C#.

So far I'm able to join and get the information from Worker and Store:

```
SELECT worker.*, store.Name AS 'Store' 
from worker inner join store on worker.Store_idStore = store.idStore
```

How do I expand this to get the relative Job's name as well?

Comment: Are you really trying to make this work for both MySQL and SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Try this One :

```
SELECT worker.*,store.Name AS store,job.Name AS job from worker inner join store on worker.Store_idStore = store.idStore and worker inner join job on worker.job_idJob = job.idJob
```

Comment: My requirement was a little different but the concept of using an "and" in your answer gave me the idea that I needed. Up-vote for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just append another inner join on the end

```
SELECT w.*,s.Name AS 'Store', j.name as 'job' from worker w
inner join store s on worker.Store_idStore = store.idStore
Inner join job J on worker.job_idjob = job.idjob
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.*, s.*, j.*
FROM worker AS w
 LEFT JOIN store AS s ON w.store_idStore = s.id
 LEFT JOIN job AS j ON w.job_idJob = j.id
```

Of course you can replace `*` with any columns' names you want. And you can add `Where` clause at the end.